# HTML5: How can I style my <header>, <footer> section into center position?

Tags: html

I found that in HTML5, 
we need to use `<header>`, `<footer>` tag instead of `<div>` tag , better approach?

However, I can't find any solution to style the   into center position?

Who can Help?

in CSS,

```
header{
???
???
}
```

Comment: Just... do it the normal way that you do with `<div>` elements?

Comment: Give it a width and set the margins to auto?

Comment: Div elements are generic while the elements you mention are more semantic. That is, they give more meaning to their content but otherwise work the same as div elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
header, footer {
   margin: auto;
   width: somePXvalue px;
}
```

Comment: Without setting the width the margin auto has no effect